# Access datarow from a workflow

Tags: powershell, workflow, datarow

I have a script which look like below:

```
function Invoke-SQL {
param(
    [string] $dataSource = ".\MSSQLSERVER",
    [string] $database = "master",
    [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
  )

$connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog=$database; Connect Timeout=100"
$connection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)

$command = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand($sqlCommand,$connection)

Try {
    $connection.Open()
} catch {
    return, $null
}

$adapter = New-Object System.Data.sqlclient.sqlDataAdapter $command
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

$connection.Close()
$dataSet.Tables

}

[string]$SQL = "select CmsSrvName from CmsServerList_VM"

$DbInstances = Invoke-SQL "DBSRV" "Test"  $SQL

workflow wf1{
Param([System.Data.DataTable]$instance)

ForEach -Parallel -ThrottleLimit 10 ($i in $instance) {
   InlineScript{
      $t = $using:i
      Write-Verbose "$t['CmsSrvName']"
       }
    }
}

wf1 -Verbose $DbInstances
```

Output:

```
VERBOSE: [localhost]:System.Data.DataRow['CmsSrvName']
VERBOSE: [localhost]:System.Data.DataRow['CmsSrvName']
VERBOSE: [localhost]:System.Data.DataRow['CmsSrvName']
```

The output is not what I expected, it just print out the type name not the value. How can I access the DataRow value in a workflow?(in Powershell 5)

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `Write-Verbose "$($t['CmsSrvName'])"`

Comment: `Write-Verbose "$t['CmsSrvName']"` is equal to `write-verbose $t + "['CmsSrvName']"`. If you need to get `['CmsSrvName']` property of the object `$t` you should remove double quotes or, as @MathiasR.Jessen suggested wrap it into `$()`.